# Having trouble in ZBar integration for QR code reader in installing app on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zbar-sdk

hi.... I am working on an application in which i need to integrate ZBar from http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html and i have done the same steps then my app works fine on simulator but when i tried to install on device then it show that erron on console with message "Failed to Upload"..

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/F1DDB587-BB90-4C20-AA8A-564ABB85FD6F/ReaderSample.app/ReaderSample
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use zbar Api for the UPC barcode scanning and its working very fine follow the below tutorial in ios 5 .please refer it and try it i have tested in devices its working well .

http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.in/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html

Thanks